# Ionic virtual scroll: screen whites out when scrolling fast

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using virtual scroll to optimize a large list of items (630 items) that I am displaying in my ionic home page.

The only reason I decided to use virtual scroll was because it takes about 1 second to load my page **without** virtual scroll. I suspect this is because, without virtual scroll, all 630 cells are created and placed in the DOM before the page is rendered rather than only the cells in the viewport. This results in a laggy, poor user experience since this page is navigated to and from many times.

Using virtual scroll is helpful since it makes the navigation faster. However, the screen "whites out" when scrolling as virtual scroll is trying to keep up and render the cells on-demand. I have tried to modify the buffer ratio attribute to create more cells upfront and diminish the "white out" effect but it doesn't seem to help.

How can I fix this "white out" effect? Is there a way to limit how fast a user can scroll to allow virtual scroll to keep up? Or is there a better way to decrease my page load time without having to use virtual scroll?

Here is my code:

**home.html**

```
  <div style="height:100%">
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="displaySongs" [approxItemHeight]="'62px'" [bufferRatio]="7">
      <button *virtualItem="let song; let i = index;"
        ion-item clear class="hymns-list-item"
        [navPush]="songPage" [navParams]=song>
          <h4 class="song-title">
              <span class="song-number">{{song.number}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ song.title }}
          </h4>
          <small class="song-genre">{{song.category}}</small>
      </button> 
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```